# What is the best way of using `<h:form>` element in JSF 2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

Is it a good idea to create facelets with a single `<h:form>` as a wrapper around all other components like this:

```
<body>
  <h:form>
    ... various inputs, commandbuttons etc. ...
  </h:form>
</body>
```

or keeping related stuff in seperate forms:

```
<body>
  <h:form id="f1">
    ... related inputs, commandbuttons etc. & ajax updates to f2 ...
  </h:form>

  <h:form id="f2">
    ... related inputs, commandbuttons etc. ...
  </h:form>
</body>
```

What are the pros/cons and possible use cases for these two different styles?

Comment: I would prefer the first one with ajax updates and other similar features. It seems to me that all of it is related and should be put within one form tag.

Comment: I am not sure about the pros/cons of each method. I am interested in some kind of answer/article that would guide me through the best practices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JSF, Is there any benefit to splitting <h:form>s?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202486/in-jsf-is-there-any-benefit-to-splitting-hforms)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Then I assume that using several forms to group related components is more desirable. And I guess it is not a common practice to stack all (related/unrelated) components into one single form, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about semantic, I would not use the first method. There's no need that all the generated HTML be wrapped up into form tags. Besides, the second method turns the code to a more legible one. 
About the ajax updates, you can easily update n elements, e.g. all the forms if you need it.